# mysql count book per user and show it in each of row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For example I've table like:

```
user_id | book     | 
------------------
 1      | aaaa     |
 1      | bbbb     | 
 2      | aaaa     |
 3      | cccc     |
```

And now I want select data with sum of all user book in each row

```
user_id | book     | count(book)
---------------------------------
 1      | aaaa     | 2
 1      | bbbb     | 2
 2      | aaaa     | 1
 3      | cccc     | 1
```

Will anyone help me?

Comment: if user_id 1 has book aaaa say three times should the count be 3 or just 1 Or is that not possible...

Comment: Is this homework? What is your actual problem with the given task? Why do you get a count of 2 for user_id 1 and book 'bbbb'? Book 'bbbb' exists only once in the sample data shown. I suggest you think this through and then write the query yourself and only come back if you have a specific problem. StackOverflow is not meant for us writing your queries. And you learn little or nothing, if you don't try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use sub select to do it

```
select user_id, book, (select count(1) from table as table2 where user_id = table.user_id ) as count_book
form table
```

Comment: You need a correlated sub-query, without GROUP BY.

Comment: You miss the aliasses at least `where user_id = table.user_id ) as count`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a join between the start table and  the count

```
 select a.user_id, a.book , b.book_count
 from my_table  
 inner join (
  select user_id, count(book) as book_count
  from my_table 
  group by user_id
  ) b on a.user_id = b.user_id
```

Comment: You forgot to declare `b`.